# Jquery click function not responding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Click is not responding!

Well this should be pretty simple. I took it from jquery apis. Must have missed something silly.

Here is my html

```
   <div id="getnext">
       Click here
    </div>
```

Here is my jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "getnext" ).click(function( event ) {
        alert( "Thanks for visiting!" );
    });
});
```

Now when i click "Click Here" nothing happens!

Comment: Please check firebug console

Comment: getnext is not a valid selector, if it is an ID or a class u should refer it as #getnext or .getnext

Comment: add **#** before getnext as **$('#getnext')**.

Comment: You forget to add # . And try to use 'on'.

Comment: jQuery works. Conclusion: *your* code is broken. Check the results of  `$(..)` (in the developer tools) when in doubt.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I was missing the fact that i was adding this element dynamically . Felix provided a solution to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `#` to target element with `id`. Also, try to use event delegation if your element has been added dynamically:

```
$(document).on('click', '#getnext', function() {
    alert( "Thanks for visiting!" );
});
```

Also, make sure that you've included jQuery properly. Put this code before your jQuery code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Felix. I was adding this element dynamically. Looks like i didn't posted the question completely. I didn't realize that this could be a cause.Will accept the answer as soon as it let me do it :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using the [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) is wrong

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $("#getnext").click(function( event ) {
        alert( "Thanks for visiting!" );
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried.Nothing happens :(

Comment: The provided code should work, it was actually a typo in your code.. Even though your code is not working properly, you should have done something wrong.. Please reproduce the issue in JSfiddle..

Comment: i tried with "#getnext" too. Actually i tried both ways. Before submitting my question here.

Comment: okay thanks. let me try with jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code you just forget to add **#** ( id selector) before id

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27NYp/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
 $( "#getnext" ).click(function( event ) {
        alert( "Thanks for visiting!" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use idor class for selecting element using juqey

Example

```
By Id: $("#elementId")
By Class: $(".elementClass")
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9hUr/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $("#getnext").on('click',function( event ) {
        alert( "Thanks for visiting!" );
    });
})
```

You must include Jquery library in your page `<head>`

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing `#` and You should use `.on` .

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#getnext" ).on('click',function(){
        alert( "Thanks for visiting!" );
    });
});
```

Make sure to load jquery library . :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'on' and check in your code any other `$(document).ready()` function is there or not. If more than one function is there it will make problem for the event raise.